# No response for Integrating Cos[2 pi x/l]/( t^2 + x^2)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I wrote below code to calculate an integration, but there is no response. Could anyone understand what is going wrong?

```
Integrate[Cos[2 Pi x/l]/( t^2 + x^2), {x, 0, l} , 
Assumptions -> t > 0  , Im[t] = 0 ,Im[l]=0]
FullSimplify[%, t > 0 , l > 0 ]
```

Comment: at first glance It seems firstly like your assumptions is not correctly defined. You need to pass a list of assumptions. Secondly rather than writing `Im[t]=0` you could write `Element[t,Reals]`. Although you end up with a complicated answer the following works for me: `Integrate[Cos[2 Pi x/l]/(t^2 + x^2), {x, 0, l}, 
 Assumptions -> {t > 0, l > 0, Element[t, Reals], Element[l, Reals]}]`

Comment: I get a response, a lot of errors, from your code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1szD9.png -- Do you really get no response?

Comment: After reading other comments,I got a response but the solution is very messy. @MichaelE2

Comment: The cosine/sine integrals can be combined (e.g. `Integrate[-Cos[s]/s, {s, (2 \[Pi] (l + I t))/l, (2 \[Pi] (l - I t))/l}` or `Integrate[Cos[s]/(2 Pi + s), {s, (2 \[Pi] (-I t))/l, (2 \[Pi] (I t))/l}`), but the result is basically what you get by hand using a partial fractions decomposition of the rational function factor in the integrand.  (Note that *Mathematica* will evaluate the integral back to a difference of `CosIntegral[]` because that's the most efficient way to represent the result in *Mathematica*.)

Answer (score 6):

This works in Mathematica 11.

```
Integrate[Cos[(2* Pi *x)/l]/(t^2 + x^2), {x, 0, l}, Assumptions -> t > 0 && l > 0]
FullSimplify[%]
```

> (1/(2 t))(-I Cosh[(2 [Pi] t)/
>       l] (CosIntegral[(2 [Pi] (l - I t))/l] - 
>        CosIntegral[(2 [Pi] (l + I t))/l] - Log[-((2 I t)/l)] + 
>        Log[(2 I t)/l]) + 
>     I Sinh[(2 [Pi] t)/
>       l] (SinhIntegral[2 [Pi] (I + t/l)] + 
>        I SinIntegral[(2 [Pi] (l + I t))/l]))

Answer (score 4):

As user64494 shows it evaluates on version 11 (with assumptions corrected).

Interestingly, substitution: $u\rightarrow x/m$, $v\rightarrow t/m$ has a different representation but appears to be same function.

```
g[t_, x_, m_] := Cos[2 Pi x/m]/(t^2 + x^2)
i = Integrate[g[t, x, m], {x, 0, m}, 
  Assumptions -> {t \[Element] Reals, t > 0, m \[Element] Reals, 
    m > 0}]
integrand = Simplify[m g[t, x, m] /. {x/m -> u, x -> m u, t -> m  v}]
si = Integrate[integrand, {u, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {v \[Element] Reals, v > 0}]
sir = si /. v -> t/m
```

[image]

for example with m=1/2:

```
Plot[{i /. m -> 1/2, sir /. m -> 1/2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]